# FreeBSD: how can I make "top" not cut off commands?

Tags: freebsd, process, top

I use `top` in a perl script for storing information about the system in DB. The actual command is:

```
top -b -d1 -a all
```

However the COMMAND field seems to be 60 chars max and everything else is cut off. Is it possible to output full commands using top? I can't find any reference to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because top doesn't provide this (no references), obviously you will need to use `ps` in your scripts.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

The GNU version of `top` that I use doesn't have the same options as your BSD version, but perhaps this same technique will work for you:

```
COLUMNS=132 top -b -d1 -a all
```